# ValueError : I/O operation on closed file (local machine OK but not Google Colab)

Tags: python, csv, file-io, io, google-colaboratory

I have some CSV files in a folder. A function was defined, to read a column of it (from each CSV file), times the values, find out the max, and print it out.

I'd like the output to be written into a text file.

The lines work well on local machine.

But when it's put on Google Colab, it produces an error, and seems keep running no stop:

```
Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(17, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(17, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 239, in dispatch_shell
    sys.stdout.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Where went wrong, and how can it be corrected?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob, sys

folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/Data folder/"

def to_cal(file_name, times):
  df['Result'] = df['Unit Price'] * times
  print (file_name, df['Result'].max())
  return

files = glob.glob(folder + "/*.csv")

with open(folder + 'output (testing).txt', 'a') as outfile:
  sys.stdout = outfile

  for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    file_name = f.replace(folder, "")
    to_cal(file_name, 10)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: when you use `with open()` then you don't need `close()` because `with` should automatically close it. The only idea that you put code with wrong indentation and now `close()` is inside `with open` and it closes file in wrong moment

Comment: is this FULL erorr? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand why you assign `sys.stdout = outfile`. Maybe colab is closing `sys.stdout` and it close also `outfile`. Or maybe in other way: when you close `outfile` then you close `sys.stdou` and this can make problem on colab.

Comment: I run it on colab and FULL error message shows very intersting: `sys.stdout.flush()`. It can confirm that problem makes `sys.stdout = outfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run it on `Colab` and FULL error message shows very intersting: `sys.stdout.flush()`.
It can confirm that problem makes `sys.stdout = outfile`.

On local computer you probably runs as `python script` so it always starts with new intepreter which uses new `sys.stdout` and `close` doesn't make problem but on `Colab` (and probably in other Python shells) it runs all time the same interpreter and when first executions closes `sys.stdout` then other execution may have problem to use it.

if you want to redirect `print()` to file then better use

```
print(..., file=outfile)
```

Or maybe write it in normal way

```
text = '{} {}\n'.format(file_name, df['Result'].max())
outfile.write(text)
```

Comment: thank you! print(..., file=outfile) works!